# Stop Skype from syncing iPhone contacts?

Tags: iphone, itunes, sync, skype, contacts

How do you stop Skype from syncing with your iPhone contacts?

It appears to do the sync whenever you sync your iPhone in iTunes.  Not sure how to turn this off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly turn **off** "Show Address Book Contacts" (despite me having it on) in the general settings to prevent Skype from grabbing your iPhone contacts.

[image]